# Does $u_n(x) = n \sin(x/n)$ converges uniformly on $[-5,7]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, uniform-convergence

I have to show that my $u_n(x)= n \sin\frac{x}{n}$ converges uniformly on $[-5,7]$.

My u(x) = $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} n \sin\frac{x}{n} = x$, so I'm trying to find my sup |$ n \sin\frac{x}{n} - x$| on $[-5,7]$. 
What I wanted to use is differential calculus $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(n \sin\frac{x}{n}-x) = \cos\frac{x}{n}-1$ 
 $\cos\frac{x}{n} - 1 \to x= 2kn\pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}. $

$$u_n(2n\pi) = n \sin\frac{2n\pi}{n}-2n\pi= $$
$$=n \sin2\pi - 2n\pi$$ 
And the endpoints: 
$$u_n(-5) = n \sin\frac{-5}{n} +5 $$ 
$$u_n(7) = n \sin\frac{7}{n} -7 $$

And I'm stuck here. I don't know how to determine whether it's uniformly convergent or not. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 4):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that$$|x|<\delta\implies\left|\frac{\sin x}x-1\right|<\frac\varepsilon7.$$Now, take $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac1N<\frac\delta7$. Then, for each $x\in[-5,7]$ and each $n\geqslant N$, $\left|\frac xn\right|<\delta$ and therefore$$\left|\frac{\sin\left(\frac xn\right)}{\frac xn}-1\right|<\frac\varepsilon7.$$So,$$\left|n\sin\left(\frac xn\right)-x\right|<\frac\varepsilon7|x|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I don't quite understand why you used $|\frac{sinx}{x} -1| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{7}$? That $\frac{\epsilon}{7}$ makes me confused

Comment: Because you are working on the interval $[-5,7]$. I took the largest distance from a point of this interval to $0$, which happens to be $7$. If your interval was $[-8,3]$, I would have taken $\frac\varepsilon8$. And what I wrote is not a comment; it's an answer.

Comment: The number $N$ should depend on the given $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @MarkViola My $N$ depends on $\delta$ and my $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: What are those relationships?  It should be straightforward to find an explicit form for $N(\varepsilon)$

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hi Jose, my friend.  I've posted a solution in which I provide a simple explicit $N$.  ;-)

Comment: @MarkViola (+1), although I still think that my answer is more natural.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Your way is sufficient to prove the UC.  However, the method doesn't give an explicit expression for $N(\varepsilon)$, which is actually easy to find and provides an added insight.

Comment: Jose, our results would be identical if it is noted that $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-1 \right|<\varepsilon/7$ whenever $|x|<\delta = \sqrt{6\varepsilon/7}$.  Then, whenever $n>N=\sqrt{7^3}{6\varepsilon}$, $\left|n\sin(x/n)-x\right|<\varepsilon$ for $x\in [-7,7]$

Answer (score 1):

We begin with the inequality

$$ |\sin(t)-t|\le \frac16|t|^3$$

Letting $t=x/n$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
|n\sin(x/n)-x|\le \frac{|x|^3}{6n^2}
\end{align}$$

If $|x|\le 7$, then for any $\varepsilon>0$,

$$|n\sin(x/n)-x|<\varepsilon$$

whenever $n>N=\sqrt{\frac{7^3}{6\varepsilon}}$.

---

> **NOTE:**

The OP found that $\sup_{x\in [-5,7]}|n\sin(x/n)-x|=|n\sin(7/n)-7|$.  Then, applying the inequality $|\sin(t)-t|\le \frac16 t^3$, we find again that for any given $\varepsilon>0$

$$\sup_{x\in [-5,7]}|n\sin(x/n)-x|\le \frac{7^3}{6n^2}<\varepsilon$$

whenever $n>n=\sqrt{\frac{7^3}{6\varepsilon}}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain me why do we limit it with $\frac{|x|^3}{6n^2}$? In the note you also wrtite $\sup_{x\in [-5,7]}|n\sin(x/n)-x|=|n\sin(7/n)-7|$. Why?

Comment: Well, $|x|\le 7$.  So, if $\frac{7^3}{6n^2}<\varepsilon$, then $\frac{|x|^3}{6n^2}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Okey, I get the idea of 7, but what about 6? Why $|\sin(t)-t|\le \frac16|t|^3$?

Comment: From the mean value theorem, it is easy to show that $|\sin(x)-x|\le \frac16 |x|^3$.  For $x>0$, let $f(x)=x-\sin(x)-\frac16 x^3$.  Note that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$ and $f'(x)=1-\cos(x)-\frac12 x^2\le 0$ for $x> 0$.  Therefore, $f(x)\le 0$ for $x\ge 0$.  Noting that $f(x)$ is an odd function of $x$, we apply absolute values and conclude.

Comment: @macaroni Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. –